# How to maintain default background color of each items inside Qt group box?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, qtstylesheets, qgroupbox

When I changed the background color of Qt group box so combobox background color is also changed. Which is inside the group box. I want default color of combobox so this is why i am not changing the bg-color of combobox. Please tell me how can I change the background color of Qt group box without changing default bg-color of inside items. I changed the background of QT group box using style sheet in qt designer (ui). I am beginner please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To style *only* the group-box, specifiy its class: `QGroupBox {background-color: green}`. For more options, see [QSS Selector Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. I didn't understand your meaning. you can add specific style to each object by using `#objectname`.

Comment: @ekhumoro this is showing error 28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'background'

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Please read my question again I changed few things i hope this make you understand what i trying to say.

Comment: @HarshGaur It's a stylesheet, not code. Change the **styleSheet** property of the group-box in Qt Designer to this: `QGroupBox {background-color: rgb(78,154,6)}`.

Comment: @HarshGaur Yes, of course. But why don't you just try it and see for yourself? Or look at the solutions you have already been given in the answers below ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should follow these steps :

1. set **specific names** for your objects :

[image]

2. select parent object and add a stylesheet to the parent like this :

[image]

3. this is the Stylesheet :

   QGroupBox#gBox1
   {
   background-color: rgb(138, 226, 52);
   }

first, you should set which kind of **class** you want like `QGroupBox`, and for set style, to the specific object you call its **object name** after `#`.

4. **out put :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Simple project with styles

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGroupBox GroupBox;
    GroupBox.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400));
    GroupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox {background-color: green}");
    
    QComboBox Combo1, Combo2;
    Combo1.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {background-color: yellow}");
    Combo2.setStyleSheet("QComboBox {background-color: red}");

    Combo1.addItem("Test1");
    Combo1.addItem("Test2");

    Combo2.addItem("Test3");
    Combo2.addItem("Test4");

    QVBoxLayout vbox;
    vbox.addWidget(&Combo1);
    vbox.addWidget(&Combo2);

    GroupBox.setLayout(&vbox);
    GroupBox.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

also you can change object name 'setObjectName(const QString &)' function and then style different objects    using there names

```
    Combo1.setObjectName("TestObject");
    Combo1.setStyleSheet("QComboBox#TestObject {background-color: yellow}");
```